# Batch script - calling commands mid-script

Tags: shell, batch-file, scripting, problem-steps-recorder

I need some ideas from yall. Mostly on how to fix this problem. I am working on trying to automate a tool that comes with most modern versions of Windows for our help desk. Its the Problem Steps Recorder, or PSE.exe. Apparently using the tool is "too hard" for some users and I thought this would be a good example to practice scripting, and learn a few things.

I actually have something that works fairly well but I have one problem that irritates the crap out of me, and I cant think of a solution, or a reason why it does this.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE PSR Script - DO NOT CLOSE, IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY CLOSE ON ITS OWN.
CD %TEMP%
MKDIR PSR
CD PSR
SET psrdir=%TEMP%\PSR
psr.exe /start /output "%psrdir%\ScreenCapture.zip" /maxsc 50 /gui 1 /stopevent 8675309
If exist "outlook.exe" "GOTO Outlook" else "GOTO Explorer"
:Outlook
start "" "OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m "support@msp.net&subject=Screen Capture&body=Please see attached file." /a "%psrdir%\ScreenCapture.zip" & GOTO exit
:Explorer
explorer.exe /n /root,%psrdir% & GOTO exit
:exit
exit
```

My problem is that once I get to starting the PSR executable, the script will hang until its closed. Ideally I would like a prompt of "Press any key to continue..." or a popup or something. Which I can then add a PSR.exe /stop, and close the program through the script. With the way its currently written, I have to tell my users to not only stop, but to close it. I know its not a big deal, but I do want to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let the program continue regardless of the state of `psr.exe` change

```
psr.exe /start /output "%psrdir%\ScreenCapture.zip" /maxsc 50 /gui 1 /stopevent 8675309
```

To

```
start psr.exe /output "%psrdir%\ScreenCapture.zip" /maxsc 50 /gui 1 /stopevent 8675309
```

To create a popup with VBS:

Batch: Use `start popup.vbs` whenever you want it to popup, or `start popup.vbs /wait` to wait for the popup to close before doing anything else.

VBS (popup.vbs):

```
Popup=msgbox("YourMessage",0,"YourTitle")
```

The `0` in the vbscript above indicates that there will only be an `ok` button. For more options, and to read more about vbs message boxes [click here](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-msgbox/).

You could, add in the following lines to create the vb file, run it, then delete it:

```
echo Popup=msgbox("Click to close",0,"YourTitle")>popup.vbs
start popup.vbs
pause
del popup.vbs
```

Comment: The problem is, while the PSR utility is open, the script is halted. Meaning no new commands are processed if I understand correctly.

The VBS saves me a little bit on how to create a popup message, but the main problem is that while the .EXE is open, the script is halted. I need a way to run the executable, then have it continue regardless of the state of the running program it called if that makes sense.

Comment: @Moridn I edited my answer to hopefully answer your question, let me know how it works out.

Comment: That worked great. I had to call the VBS script through batch, which is less than ideal, but its working perfectly. I was hoping to avoid having to use multiple files, as I will have to zip it up, and Outlook dosent like .ZIP attachments.

Know of any way to call that VBS in the batch file directly, or start with VBS and call the original?

Comment: @Moridn Glad to hear it worked out, and welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Moridn Well, you could create a temporary VBS with batch, run it, then delete it when the popup is finished. If you want to know how to do this, let me know and i'll edit my answer.

Comment: I would actually. I am in the process of learning VB and C#, so hopefully I will understand it.

Comment: @Moridn Edited it in.